# Using more than one delimiter for .split method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, split, delimiter

I want to split a string into an array by `";"`, `" "` and `","` delimiters in one line. Is there a way to do that without using regex?

Comment: No, there isn't--why do you want to not use a regex? `<pedantry>`You're not splitting an array.`</pedantry>`

Comment: What is stopping you not to use _regex_ ?

Comment: split an array or a string? Please provide an example.

Comment: @daremkd Of-course _string_ :-)

Comment: @DaveNewton I am very new to Ruby, and wanted to know if there is another built-in alternative (besides regex) to passing multiple delimiters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just replace the delimiters by one delimiter and split on that.

```
p "aaa;bbb ccc,ddd".tr(";,"," ").split  #=> ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]
```

Comment: Love it! this is a very clever solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: @steenslag Oh, missed that in the OP somehow :/

Answer (score 9):

Yes. Possible but with *regex*.

```
string.split(/[;, ]/)
```

Comment: `array.split(/[;, ]/)`

Comment: @MarkThomas Yes.. That's too nice!

Comment: @MarkThomas We don't have method `Array#split`.. :p

Comment: that's because the `array` variable contains a string ;) (oops)

Comment: Good recovery, @MarkThomas.